# Какой язык выбрать?

Tags: php, c#, python, ruby

Всем привет
Изучил фронтэнд, пришло время бекенда. С какого языка легче всего начать погружение в мир бэкенда ( нужно и с базами данных работать). Что посоветуете?

Comment: Тот язык, который знает знакомый вам эксперт, с которым вы можете лицом к лицу общаться.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы уже знаете JavaScript посмотрите в сторону node.js